# Finding the centroid of a SQL Geography type polygon

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

I have a WKT polygon that I want to find the centroid of.
The database I am using has Geography type fields to store my spatial information.
I'm working on a list of WKT 4326 strings, checking they are valid and making them valid if not.
After this I want to calculate the centroid of these polygons.
I can see that MS SQL STCentroid returns a geometry type.
Can anyone tell me what are the implications of storing this centroid in a Geography type?

...and why is there not an STCentroid equivalent for the Geography type?

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: There is the [EnvelopeCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/envelopecenter-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) method which may be an appropriate approximation of the centroid. Have you seen that and considered it instead?

Comment: Consider a square centred on the north pole and a second square centred on the south pole. Where, sensibly, do you think the centroid of that should be?

Comment: EnvelopeCenter looks interesting, thanks. Re your second comment, I don't follow you. Are you talking about finding the centroid of multiple polygons?

Answer (score 2):

While this is a year after your question was asked, I'm hoping this answer helps any future readers, like myself, who find this question asking the same thing.

**To answer the question in your title regarding finding the centroid of an SQL  GEOGRAPHY object:**

You can use [EnvelopeCenter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/envelopecenter-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the approximate center, as a circle, of the `GEOGRAPHY`.  This returns a `GEOGRAPHY` object, but you can then extract a center from it to get a lat/lon like so:

```sql
DECLARE @g geography = 'LINESTRING(-120 45, -120 0, -90 0)';
DECLARE @lat FLOAT,
        @lon FLOAT

@lat = @g.EnvelopeCenter().Lat
@lon = @g.EnvelopeCenter().Long
```

---

> Can anyone tell me what are the implications of storing this centroid in a Geography type?

> ...and why is there not an STCentroid equivalent for the Geography type?

I am assuming you mean `GEOMETRY` here?  If so...

I would not recommend converting this into a `GEOMETRY` and using `STCentroid()` as some articles, like [this](https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/geospatial-data-analysis-using-sql-3bf3b5f38d51) one, would suggest, as it only works *some* of the time.  Because a `GEOMETRY` object is a flat 2D object, you cannot accurately take a flat area from a shape like the Earth, especially as you get closer to the poles, unlike a `GEOGRAPHY` object which is designed to account for this.  It's not mathematically possible to form a flat rectangle from a sphere without distortion of some kind.  The closer you are to the equator, the less distortion you experience, but at the poles it can be very exaggerated.

To see this in detail, you can check out this website that shows the true sizes of countries when looking at a flat map:
https://www.thetruesize.com/

See this fascinating video from [Vox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIID5FDi2JQ&feature=emb_imp_woyt) if you would like more info.